# how to divide hours in php?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have tried to search for the answer for my problem for quite a while now and I did not solve it yet. I am new to PHP.

Problem.

Divide 2:00 by 2 `(hr/2)` = 1:00 //format h:i

Thanks.

Comment: You are saying that you need to divide `2:00`? Or is it `2.00`? (Note the colon and dot)

Comment: use strtotime() function

Comment: check answer below

Comment: So if the time is 3:00, you want it to be 1:30? What happens on times that is not easily divided? Say 1:15. do you want to write it out in seconds too then?

Comment: Basically the answer is half of the time.

Comment: @NishitManjarawala , The output of your answer is wrong. I have check it. Thanks anyway

Comment: is that 2:00 2 hours or 2 o'clock, if it's 2 hours then you can convert it into minutes and then half it and then convert it into h:i format again

Answer (score 4):

I think the safest way is to convert to seconds and use date to display it.

```
$time ="3:00";

list($hours, $minutes) = explode(":", $time);
$minutes += $hours*60;
$seconds = $minutes*60;
date_default_timezone_set ("UTC"); // makes sure there is no DST or timezone added to result
echo "new time: " . date("h:i", $seconds/2);  // 01:30
```

Your question states "h:i" format yet it's written as "1:00".
To get 1:00 you need to use format "G:i".
https://3v4l.org/4MjVQ

Comment: This is what I need :) Thanks

Comment: php 5+ gives convenient implementations in `DateTime` and `DateInterval`. I think those are better than this..

Comment: @RomeoSierra But DateTime does not support the input string OP has. At least not in your answer

Answer (score 0):

For the record, dividing time is trivial in any programming/scripting language. Because if we are talking about a timestamp, dividing that would make no sense, because a timestamp is a particular point on the line of chronology.

Time duration in the other hand, could be divided. However, I am not so sure if php's API has any implementation for time duration handling. Still you can go on for your own customized implementation to handle time intervals. It would be something like follows.

```
<?php
    #We need at least two timestamps to get a duration
    $time1 = new DateTime("2018-4-23 10:00:00");
    $time2 = new DateTime("2018-4-23 11:00:00");

    $durationInSeconds = ($time2->getTimestamp()) - ($time1->getTimestamp()); //Get the interval in seconds
    #echo $durationInSeconds; // Gives you 3600 seconds
    # Now you can divide these seconds into anything you prefer.
    # Let's say I want two intervals. This means, I have to go for the timestamp in between the two. I could do that by simply adding half the amount of seconds
    $halfDurationInSeconds = $durationInSeconds / 2;
    $time1->add(new DateInterval("PT".$halfDurationInSeconds."S")); // adds 1800 secs
    echo $time1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. Use strtotime

```
$your_time = "12:00";
date_default_timezone_set ("UTC");
$secs = strtotime($your_time ) - strtotime("00:00:00");
echo date("H:i:s",$secs / 2);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think we can also use multiplication here. Thanks for the suggestions above. It really did help me a lot. This is my modified code for the suggestions above.

```
function multiplyTime ($multiple, $prescribeWorkingHrs) {
    list($hours, $minutes) = explode(":", $prescribeWorkingHrs);
    $minutes += $hours*60;
    $seconds = $minutes*60;
    $product = $seconds * $multiple;

    return date("h:i", $product);
}
```

Results:

```
multiplyTime(0.75, "8:00") = "6:00"
multiplyTime(0.5, "8:00") = "4:00"
multiplyTime(0.25, "8:00") = "2:00"
```

Hope this will help too. Thanks